# Firebase authentication implementation for a single page angular application and spring-boot backend

Tags: spring, angular, firebase, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to secure my single page Angular 5 application that has a spring boot backend with firebase authentication.

Is the following a good way to implement this.

1. All requests that do not start with **/api** are forwarded to index.html with `forward:/index.html`. The AuthGuard in my Angular app will then handle whether the user has access or needs to login.
2. All requests going to **/api/**** have to be authenticated. Here the firebase user token will be set in the header of the request by Angular and my custom Spring authentication filter and authentication provider vill handle it.

Are there any tutorials, specifically for the spring part of the implementation, that I can look at. I haven't found any thing similar and I want to be sure that the security implementation is done correctly.

Comment: Did you resolve?